# I can no longer receive service medals

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I had these services medals unlocked: The shirt, the big spender and the recruiting officer. They just disappeared. What happened? How do I get them back?  Also during the last update I lost about 200,000 coins and 60 bux.  Any idea how to get these back?

Answer (score 1):

The service medals was for a limited time period (10 days) and they are no longer available to collect.

Can't help with the bux/coins problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you can do about the medals as mhazeltine said, but for the missing coins and bux then email the developer ( support@disneymobile.com ) and describe to them the problem and they should be able to help you on it.